# Passing and persisting a connection string in WPF using MVVM pattern?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, connection-string, unity-container

My app needs to be able to store the connection string from the login module to be available to all other modules in the application, of which there are 50 or so.  I originally intended to make the connection string available through broadcasting and subscribing to a new/changed connection string event, but because most/all of the 50 modules are loaded on demand they are unable to subscribe to the event during the login process since they are loaded after the login process.  Based on my understanding I need a different approach to make the connection string available.

I then thought about placing the connection string in the shell and attempting to expose it to any loaded module but I cannot find a way to do that without breaking the MVVM pattern and introducing unwanted dependencies.

If anyone knows of a way to implement either of the above two options I would be very interested to know if it could be done while folowing the MVVM pattern.

I am thinking now that the best approach would be to use some variation of a singleton for the connection string as a shared service.  I would love for the Unity Container to be able to store the connection string and I could use a service locator to access it in any module but I do not know how to do this.  Any examples that are similar in nature have been in MEF and/or Silverlight.  **Has anyone done this in WPF or have an example of how to write a connection string singleton and add it to the Unity Container? A guide, tutorial, or some code snippets would be greatly appreciated!**

**Note:** I am using Prism and Unity, Oracle on the backend and the app will be deployed on a Citrix server (where in the name of security they have blocked developers from writing to the app.config) which is why I cannot use that approach.  **Also will using a Singleton for the connection string cause problems when multiple users run the app off of Citrix?  Will every user have their own singleton connection string?**  If not, then my whole question changes, is there a good approach I can use to pass/persist the connection string between all of my modules?

Comment: There are several ways, but it depends on how the sequence of events.  Are your dependent modules loaded at the same time as the login module, or is the login module loaded, then the other modules are loaded after login is complete?

Comment: @Backlash The dependent modules are loaded after the login is completed.  The login module is the very first, then a menu module, then any number of modules depending on the menu selection.

Comment: It starts to get a little "chatty" if you take this route but one option would be to make the modules send out a request for the connection string whenever they are loaded, which the login module would then reply to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about how to go about registering the connection string in your Unity Container you should be able to achieve the desired result with the following snippets.

Storing the connection string:

```
Container.RegisterInstance<string>("ConnectionString", theConnectionString);
```

Retrieving the connection string:

```
var connectionString = Container.Resolve<string>("ConnectionString");
```

As I mentioned in the comment above another alternative might be to create a request and a response type that you can send back and forth using the EventAggregator, letting each module ask for the connection string and let the Login module reply.

```
var MyToken = Guid.NewGuid();

EventAggregator.GetEvent<ConnectionStringResponse>().Subscribe(r => {
    if(r.Token != MyToken)  // Make sure we're only handling responses to our request.
        return;

    ConnectionString = r.ConnectionString;
    // Kick off whatever other stuff you need to do once
    // you've gotten the connection string
    // Might also want to unsubscribe at this point unless you want
    // to go even further and handle changing connection strings.
});

EventAggregator.GetEvent<ConnectionStringRequest>().Publish(MyToken);
```

Comment: thank you, your solution of registering the string works perfect. I agree with the answer below that the cleanest approach would be to build an interface and class for the connection string and register that with the Unity Container. But for now your approach is perfect.  

Also the event approach you suggest sounds so obvious when I hear it, I thought I needed to broadcast the event when the connection string is changed/set, but it works better to broadcast an event when a new module is loaded that needs the connection string.

Comment: I would agree that creating a `Type` to resolve (something like `ConnectionStringProvider`, or even an interface) here would be the better choice down the road if you want to keep using the Container approach. Either that or at least make the name somewhat refactor-proof by making it a string constant available to all your modules. (Much like how RegionNames are often handled)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Prism, I would strongly recommend Unity Container registering the connection string and ctor-dependency injecting it into the various VMs that you have.

Sort of like, define the contract where other assemblies/VMs can consume it, and the implementation in the LoginModule:

```
class ConnectionInfo : IConnectionInfo 
{
    public GetConnectionString()
    {
      // you get the drift...!  
      // you should probably cache the result into a Lazy<T> impl. and just return
      // that value on future calls, to save the lookup of the config.
    }
}
```

Register it in the login module:

```
container.RegisterType<IConnectionInfo, ConnectionInfo>(
  new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

And DI it in the ctor of your VMs - it's hassle-free, at this point:

```
public MyViewModel(IConnectionInfo connectionInfo_)
{
  var connectionString = connectionInfo_.GetConnectionString();
}
```

I guess my preferred approach to these situations is to prefer interfaces above IEventAggregator, if I get to choose. It just makes it easier to handle situations like late created VMs not picking up IEA signals because the event signalling happened too early. That would lead to some real painful technical debt accumulation.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest solution in applying MVVM, building an interface and connection string class to be injected into each view model.  Instead of simply registering the string instance "connection string" as suggested in the above answer.  I will convert to this in the future for production.